# Akka-http - write to response output stream

Tags: scala, akka-http

I need to create a large tab separated file as a response to HTTP GET request.
In my route a create some Scala objects and then I want to write some custom representation of those objects to the Output Stream.

It is not just serialization to tab separated instead of JSON, because I need also to create a header with column names, so IMHO this can't be solved with custom marshaling.

So how can I get a writer or outputstream from HttpRequest?

Something like

```
 ~path("export") {
        get {
              val sampleExonRPKMs = exonRPKMService.getRPKMs(samples)
              val writer = HttpResponse().getWriter // this does not exists
              writeHeader(writer)
              ... // write objects tab separated
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can complete an Akka HTTP route with a marshallable source. If you don't want to use custom marshallers, you can always complete with a `Source[ByteString, _]`. See the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html) for more info.

Your route will look something like

```
get {
  val sampleExonRPKMs = exonRPKMService.getRPKMs(samples)
  val headers: String = ???
  Source.single(headers).concat(Source(sampleExonRPKMs).map(_.toTSVLine)).intersperse("\n").map(ByteString.apply)
}
```

Note as a separate issue: if you are dealing with large amounts of data, the `getRPKMs` call will result in loading all of it in memory.

Comment: This code creates me exception on marshalling:

org.json4s.package$MappingException: Unexpected type info AnnotatedType(TypeRefType(NoPrefixType,TypeSymbol(T, owner=0, flags=12100, info=33 ),List()),List(40))