# How to stream apache poi xls workbook directly to akka-http response?

Tags: scala, apache-poi, akka-stream, akka-http

Is it a way to *avoid* writing Apache POI workbook to byte array or to temp file and just stream it into akka-http response?

```scala
val wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook())
...building workbook...
val os = new ByteArrayOutputStream() //or buffered file output stream
wb.write(os) // <- can I just get from akka-http some output stream to write workbook directly to response?
```

Comment: You can complete a route with Source[ByteString] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503489/akka-http-write-to-response-output-stream

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc As I got, in this example they got whole data in memory and then created Source from it. Can you please give me code example writing data to response directly from workbook?

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can pass a `Source[ByteString, _]` as `complete` of a route

```scala
val route: Route = get {
  val (out, source) = StreamConverters.asOutputStream().preMaterialize()
  writeAsync(out)
  complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, source))
}
```

The `writeAsync` may look like this but you need to use `new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook()).write(os)` here

```scala
def writeAsync(out: OutputStream): Unit = {
  val random = new Random()
  Future {
    1 until 10000 foreach { _ =>
      out.write(random.nextPrintableChar().toInt)
    }
    out.close()
  }
}
```

Method `out.write` will be blocked till there is demand sent to the `Source`. The timeout for blocking is configured via `asOutputStream()` method